# How can I pause recording in windows G

Tags: recording

In Windows 10 we have this feature. Press windows G and we can record games. I love it. I upload those to youtube.

BTW what's the feature name? Game bar.

Now I would love to record overwatch.

The thing is the way overwatch works is I have to wait for a while before I play again. So I cannot record 1 hour video. I got to stop after each play.

Say I want to pause recording. How would I do so?

Comment: This will give you some insight to this feature. http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-on-windows/social/record-game-clips-game-dvr-windows-10

Comment: no option to pause there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I'm a few years late but Windows 10 also has this awesome thing called Video Editor. Record the whole thing then trim it. You can also put two seperate recordings together and save it as one, so it will typically become one.